# Batch script to delete older backup files in a folder created by date with the exception of the newest 5 files

Tags: file, batch-file, delete-file

I have a program that creates a backup every 30 minutes, but does not delete older files. I am looking to make a script that will run on task scheduler that will look in the folder that is created by the program. It creates folder by date as follows /year/month/day/*name of file.zip. I have done a little research and come up with

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens= 2" %%i in ( WMIC OS GET localdatetime /format:value ) do set localTime=%%i
set "YYYY=%localTime:~0,4%"
set "M=%localTime:~4,1%"
set "MM=%localTime:~5,1%"
set "D=%localTime:~6,1%"
set "DD=%localTime:~7,1%"
if %M%==0 set M=
if %D%==0 set D=
cd /d "~%~dp0"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%X IN ('dir .\%YYYY%\%M%%MM%\%D%%DD%\Backup-serversave-%YYYY%-%M%%MM%-%D%%DD%--*.zip /b /o:-d') DO set FILENAME=%%~X
rem FILENAME now contains the last element
if "%FILENAME%" neq "" DEL "%FILENAME%"
pause
```

This script looks in the folder by todays date and than should delete the file that is oldest in the folder. But every time I run it, all I get is a "cannot find file" and it tells me the exact file that it says it can't find. So I need a little help to make it work. It would be also great if there is any way to make it only delete after five files are in the folder. If anyone can help me that would be amazing.

Update. Got a good answer but need a little more help. If anyone out there can find a way to make it delete yesterdays folder at the change of the day that would be amazing I am looking all over and so far have found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did already a quite good job on writing the batch file, but made some small mistakes.

Using in first line `ECHO ON` helped to find those mistakes.

The following lines with some corrections for the batch file work.

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%i in ( `WMIC OS GET localdatetime /format:value` ) do set localTime=%%i
set "YYYY=%localTime:~0,4%"
set "M=%localTime:~4,1%"
set "MM=%localTime:~5,1%"
set "D=%localTime:~6,1%"
set "DD=%localTime:~7,1%"
if %M%==0 set M=
if %D%==0 set D=
cd /d "%~dp0"
for /F "usebackq tokens=* skip=5" %%X in ( `dir .\%YYYY%\%M%%MM%\%D%%DD%\Backup-serversave-%YYYY%-%M%%MM%-%D%%DD%--*.zip /b /o:-d` ) do del .\%YYYY%\%M%%MM%\%D%%DD%\%%X
pause
```

No file was not deleted ever because you used command `dir` to find the ZIP files in a subdirectory. The name of a found file was referenced with `%%X`, but without the path to this file. As the batch file did not change into the directory on which `dir` searched for the ZIP files, command `DEL` could not find the file to delete in the current working directory.

The first 5 lines returned by command `dir` containing the 5 newest files according to last modification date are ignored by using `skip=5`. Therefore only files with todays date in name and older than the first 5 files in directory listing are deleted and the newest 5 files are kept.

There was also a mistake in line with command `cd` and some other small mistakes all found by using `ECHO ON` in first line.

Comment: there was something else as well i was wondering since this changes days when the new day happens is there any way to delete the previous days folder at the start of the new day period

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the previous day folders is difficult if the batch file should find out automatically which folders should be deleted and which folders should be kept.

Here is a solution which makes this task simple and which can be appended to the other lines in my other answer for deleting the older backup files.

```
if exist .\%YYYY%\%M%%MM%\%D%%DD%\Backup-serversave-%YYYY%-%M%%MM%-%D%%DD%--*.zip (
   md TempBackup
   copy /V .\%YYYY%\%M%%MM%\%D%%DD%\*.zip TempBackup >nul
   for /F "usebackq" %%D in ( `dir /AD /B 20*` ) do rd /S /Q %%D
   md %YYYY%\%M%%MM%\%D%%DD%
   copy /V TempBackup\*.zip %YYYY%\%M%%MM%\%D%%DD% >nul
   rd /S /Q TempBackup
)
```

First, a check is made if there are already ZIP files today stored to prevent deleting older backups if not at least one backup is created today.

Next a directory with name `TempBackup` is created into which are copied the currently existing backup files created today.

Then a `dir` command is executed which lists only the names of the directories starting with `20`. Currently this is just the directory `2014`, but on 2015-01-01 it will be additionally `2015`. All those directories are recursively and silently deleted.

Next the directory tree for today is recreated and the ZIP files are copied back into this directory.

Finally the temporary backup directory for the ZIP files is deleted, too.

I'm wondering now why using a directory with current year as name containing a directory with current month as name containing a directory with current day of month as name if the ZIP files itself contain also year, month and day in name, and all ZIP files except the last 5 ZIP files saved today should be deleted?

It would be perhaps easier to manage to create all ZIP files in same directory and delete all ZIP files except the last 5 according to last modification date.

On the other hand the management with directories make it possible to keep backups from several days like one month and just delete the backup of previous month from time to time either manually or automatically for example on 15th of every month.

Comment: its just the program i am using it creates it that way on its own i cant change the way it does it as i did not create it but i have to use it i was trying something like this myself with mixed results trying to work off what you showed me for the files and adapting it for the directory 

        
for /f "usebackq tokens=* skip=1" %%A in ( 'dir C:\Users\kain184\AppData\Roaming\.technic\modpacks\kainspack\backups\serversave\%YYYY%\%M%%MM% /ad /b /o-d' ) do rmdir /s /q C:\Users\kain184\AppData\Roaming\.technic\modpacks\kainspack\backups\serversave\%YYYY%\%M%%MM%\%%A